# How JAVA11 use SPI to load SQL Driver Class

Tags: java, java-11

In Java8 there is a static block in java.sql.DriverManger class as

```
    static {
        loadInitialDrivers();
        println("JDBC DriverManager initialized");
    }
```

It will be executed when java.sql.DriverManger class is loaded by ClassLoader, and it will call the ServiceLoader.load() method to start to scan files under META-IFO/services folder in jars under the classpath. In this way it register all the Driver class defined in services folder.
However, in Java11, it don't have this static block anymore, I was wondering how Java11 starts the SPI process. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange!  This question is not related to Serial Peripheral Interface, so I have removed the SPI tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 11 the scanning for the drivers is only started when the first connection is opened:

[`DriverManager.getConnection(String url)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#L247)

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url)
    throws SQLException {

    java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
    return (getConnection(url, info, Reflection.getCallerClass()));
}
```

calls [`DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info, Class<?> caller)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#L646):

```
private static Connection getConnection(
    String url, java.util.Properties info, Class<?> caller) throws SQLException {
    // [..]
    ensureDriversInitialized();
    // [..]
}
```

which in turn calls [`DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#L570) which finally uses the `java.util.ServiceLoader` class to effectively load the drivers:

```
private static void ensureDriversInitialized() {
    // [..]
                    ServiceLoader<Driver> loadedDrivers = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class);
    // [..]
}
```